# Elastic Search Date Range Filter lambda expression issue

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using Nest for ElasticSearch. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1EH7.jpg)

part of the index looks like this    "startdate" : "2018-11-01T00:00:00",          "enddate" : "2018-11-01T00:00:00"
My fluentAPI query looks like below

```
 var response = client.Search<ActivityReportsSearchViewModel>(x => x
                    .Size(500)
                    .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must
                    (mu => mu.MultiMatch(m => m
                        .Fields(n => n.Fields(f => f.User, f => f.Activity
                            , f => f.County, f => f.Constituency, f => f.Country
                            , f => f.ActivityRequestDescription, f => f.ActivityDescription,
                            f => f.LessonsLearnt, f => f.Challenges, f => f.Recommendatinons, f => f.User
                            , f => f.Venue, f => f.Division))
                        .Query(**search**)))
                .**Filter**(fi => fi
                    .DateRange(r => r
                        .Field(f => f.StartDate)
                        .GreaterThan("2018-08-20")
                        .LessThanOrEquals(DateMath.Now)
                    )))));
```

The query runs well and return results **WITHOUT** filter. After I add filter as shown above the query returns no results. Can anyone point the problem with the fluentAPI code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `response.IsValid` to determine whether the request is valid for the API call to Elasticsearch.

The `response.DebugInformation` will provide more details about the API call in a friendly to read format, including if there is an error. If it is an error in Elasticsearch, `response.ServerError` will be populated with the details.

Without knowing further details about the response, I suspect the problem is an issue with parsing the string `"2018-08-20"` as a date on the Elasticsearch server side. Elasticsearch will attempt to parse the string into a date using the format specified in the `date` field mapping for `StartDate`, and if the date in the search request is in a different format, you can supply the format in the [`DateRange` query with `.Format(...)`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-range-query-usage.html).

Assuming that the document was originally indexed with the .NET client and the default `DateTime` serialization was used, you should just be able to use an instance of `DateTime` to supply the needed date

```
.DateRange(r => r
    .Field(f => f.StartDate)
    .GreaterThan(new DateTime(2018, 8, 20))
    .LessThanOrEquals(DateMath.Now)
)
```

which will serialize as

```
"2018-08-20T00:00:00"
```

which is the same format as the field in the index. Alternatively, you can pass the string in this format.

Comment: thanks @russ-cam .
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.5864321
# Request:
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"range":{"startDate":{"gt":"2018-08-20T00:00:00","lte":"now"}}}],"must":[{"multi_match":{"fields":["user","activity","county","activityRequestDescription","activityDescription","lessonsLearnt","challenges","recommendatinons","user","venue","division","officers"],"query":"gathairu"}}]}},"size":500}
# Response:
{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

Comment: Debug information is as above. The query didnt yeid any result as earlier indicated. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so the query executes correctly. If you have an example of a document that you believe should be returned by the query but is not, you can use the Explain API to see why it didn't: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

Comment: The issue on the above code lies "StartDate", had to revice my entire class to lower case properties. Thanks Russ for the tip on debug-information

Comment: Issue resolved by converting the properties to lowercase